# How can i use mod_rewrite to accept special characters?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

On my site i have saved some of the users searches but if they enter a string with special characters then my mod_rewrite rule gives a 400 Bad Request.

How can i fix it?

```
RewriteRule ^search/([^/\.]*)/?$ /index.php?page=search&string=$1 [NC,L]
```

for example, If a saved search is:

```
/search/%spong%US%/
```

Thanks

Comment: [What every web developer must know about URL encoding](http://blog.lunatech.com/2009/02/03/what-every-web-developer-must-know-about-url-encoding)

Comment: `%` should be entered as `%25` in your URL.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that RewriteRule is looking at the URL after decoding by the server.  You have two options:

1) Capture the search string from %{THE_REQUEST} in a rewritecond, which will still be in encoded form.

2) Use the [B] flag to escape the backreferences in your substitution.